# Find in Files Finding Files not in Solution

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I have encountered some weird behaviour in VS2010. When I perform a Find in Files for some text, and select Entire Solution in the Look In field, I get back file that are not part of my solution in the Results window. I have checked to see if these files have been accidentally added to my solution and cannot see them in the Solution Explorer, so can anybody tell me why this is happening, and how I can prevent these files showing up in my search, as I could accidentally enter one to make changes without realising they are the wrong solution.

Thanks,

Michael

Answer (score 0):

Performed a Clean Solution and that seems to have stopped the files appearing. Would love to know how it happened though.